# render seems to be triggering before componentDidMount (async/await used)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

my problem does have a workaround, but I am interested in the underlying problem.

In my component AuthorProfile, I am using async/await to fetch data, then setting my state with the fetched data, and using console log in render() to see what is going on, here is my component without the render function:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { displayData: [] };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getRoadmapByUser({
      user_id: this.props.location.pathname.slice(9)
    });
    this.setState({
      displayData: this.props.auth.other_author_created_roadmaps
    });

  }
```

In render I have `return(blah blah blah... {console.log(this.state.displayData)}`,**when I load my page, my console will always print blank lines for like 2 times (since that was my displayData state at first), and then starts logging the fetched data**. That shouldn't be the case, I used async/await. My quick workaround is simple for my application, I am trying to display a list which will use .map, I inititaed displayData to an empty array so that even if there is no data .map wouldn't call any errors.

Here is my code on how I fetched the data: 
In componentDidMount of my component "AuthorProfile":

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getRoadmapByUser({
      user_id: this.props.location.pathname.slice(9)
    });
  }
```

This will trigger a redux action getRoadmapByUser which looks like:

```
 export const getRoadmapByUser = id => dispatch => {
   return axios
    .post("/api/users/getroadmapbyuser", id)
    .then(res => dispatch({ type: GET_ROADMAPS_BY_USER, payload: res.data }));
};
```

This makes an api call and then uses the data retrieved from the api call to do a dispatch, here is the post /api/users/getroadmapbyuser call:

```
router.post("/getroadmapbyuser", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.body.user_id }).then(user =>
    res.json(user.createdRoadmap)
  );
});
```

This will return a field in my database, now I am going to update my redux state with the .then(res => dispatch.....,) the dispatch looks like this:

```
 case GET_ROADMAPS_BY_USER:
  return {
    ...state,
    other_author_created_roadmaps: action.payload
  };
```

I will at last use this other_author_created roadmaps data and set my displayData equal to it.

Comment: componentDidMount is triggered only after initial render and it won't make any difference even if you use async await in it

Comment: that's very intereesting, I had the wrong perception of componentDidMount always before first render for a long time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected(correct) behavior, you can reference this lifecycle diagram [here](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

The constructor function run first, then render function, then componentDidMount.

And according to react document [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

"You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case..."

Answer (score 0):

Having redux dispatch an action in componentDidMount would also act like setState and trigger extra rendering. I would ask though, what exactly are you trying to do ? cos i don't find that behaviour strange or weird at all

Comment: my bad, thought that componenetDidMount always triggered before the initial rendering.